# Parallel mesh partitioning

Tags: finite-element, parallel-computing, mesh, unstructured-mesh

When a mesh partitioning takes place and every process works on a part of the mesh is any way to rename the global numbering of nodes(on each process) into a local numbering?Is there any software that can do it?

Comment: What mesh partitioner you use? Metis? ParMetis? SCOTCH?

Comment: I am studying metis but i do not know if it gives a local numbering after partitioning

Comment: I think you have some confusion here. Metis gives you the processor id for each cell in your mesh, but you need to handle global or local ids of cells or nodes yourself.

Comment: Thank you.I am asking if there is any possibility also to get a local node numbering in order to formulate the stiffness matrix for each part of the mesh in each proccessor

Answer (score 2):

All software I know of first enumerates nodes locally, and then uses this local enumeration to generate a global enumeration.

I suggest that you want to read the following manuscript about all of these questions: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2010-distributed.pdf In particular, section 3 is relevant to you. The full reference for this paper is as follows:

> Wolfgang Bangerth, Carsten Burstedde, Timo Heister, Martin Kronbichler: "Algorithms and data structures for massively parallel generic adaptive finite element codes". ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, vol. 38 (2011), pp. 14/1-28.